# R function catdes in Python (description by categories of a subpopulation)

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn

The R function catdes, allows to see whether each sub-population can be characterized by the categorical variables, categories and continuous variables of the data set. The function catdes is availabe in package FactoMineR.

```
catdes(...)
```

Is there such a function or library available to characterize subpopulations in python ? In my case the subpopulations are the output of a clustering exection using scikit library